# I'm trying to write a function that Randomizes a number (range 0..100), then prints all the odd numbers from 40 to that one

Tags: javascript, function

I'm new to JavaScript and i'm struggling with the basics. I can't get this code to work.

I'm trying to create a function that (the following is taken form the exercise I'm doing) randomizes a number (range 0..100), then prints all the odd numbers from 40 to that one. If the number was smaller than 40, print all the numbers down to the randomized one (i.e. if the result was 37, you 
should print: 40, 39, 38, 37).

Your input would be greatly appreciated.

```
var sol3 = function() {
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);

    if (n > 40) {
        for( var i = 41; i <= 100; i++2);
        console.log(i);
    }
    else if (n < 40) {
        for (var i = 39; i <= 40; i--2);
        console.log(i);
    }

    return i;
};

so13();
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? This needs to be tagged as homework also.

Comment: Start by fixing the syntax errors.  If you are using the console, it should be telling you about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems with your code -

1. `i++2` is incorrect
2. `;` after `for` is incorrect
3. `i--2` is incorrect
4. you are calling `sol13()` that is number 1 there not letter l
5. `return i` but it works!

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ThEmh/)

```
var sol3 = function () {
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

    console.log("n = " + n);

    if (n > 40) {

        for (var i = 41; i <= n; i += 2)
            console.log(i);

    } else if (n < 40) {

        for (var i = 40; i >= n; i--)
            console.log(i);
    }

    return i;

};

sol3();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out all those issues... I would never have spotted that I was calling the function with a 1 instead of an l!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

`for (var i = 39; i <= 40; i--2);`

to:

`for (var i = 39; i >=0; i-=2)`

Also change the first for loop from `i++2` to `i+=2`

Answer (score 0):

```
var sol3 = function() {

    var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    var odds = new Array();
    console.log("n:" + n);

    if (n > 40) {        
        for (var i = 41; i <= n; i+=2) {
            console.log(i);
            odds.push(i);
        }
    }
    else {        
        for (var i = 39; i >= n; i-=2) {
            console.log(i);
            odds.push(i);
        }
    }
    return odds;
};

sol3();
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the .push, i'll look it up. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
var sol3 = function(){

    var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);

    if (n > 40){
        while( n < 100){
            if( n%2==1){
                console.log(n);
            }
            n++;
        }
    }
    else if (n < 40) {
        for (var i = 39; i >= n; i--){
            console.log(i);
            }
    }
    return i;
};
sol();
```